# Filling the button value from an array through the ID in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-mobile, getelementbyid

I have started to create a Quiz. All Questions and answers are today in the same array. Over the id's `b1 - b4` and the function `getElementById`, it was a success with HTMl, JavaScript and CSS.

But now I want to "convert" this script in to a mobile version. So I started to work with jQuery Mobile. I changed getElementById into `$("#variable").val(array);`. And checked it with Firebug. Firebug tells me, that the value of the button was filled with the Array-values, but I can't see it in the normal view..

Can someone tell me a solution of my mistakes?

HTML-Buttons

```
                <input id='b1' type="button" value="" ONCLICK="analyseB1()"/>

                <input id='b2' type="button" value=""  ONCLICK="analyseB2()"/>


                <input id='b3' type="button" value=""  ONCLICK="analyseB3()"/>

                <input id='b4' type="button" value=""  ONCLICK="analyseB4()"/>

                <input id='next' type="button" value="Next Question" ONCLICK="next()"/>
```

JS-Function

```
function next()
{   
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = array[questioncounter][0];
    $("#b1").val(array[questioncounter][1]);
    $("#b2").val(array[questioncounter][2]);
    $("#b3").val(array[questioncounter][3]);
    $("#b4").val(array[questioncounter][4]);

    document.getElementById('next').style.display='none';

    document.getElementById('b1').style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.getElementById('b2').style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.getElementById('b3').style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.getElementById('b4').style.backgroundColor = '';
```

}

Comment: It's good practice (especially if you post here) to name variables and functions in English

Comment: Jes you are right, I have changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion here is to learn some jQuery programming, you'll see it's fundamental. Now, about your problem:

- use `<a href="#" id="b1" data-role="button"></a>` to create buttons
- do not use `onclick` handlers
- use a smart jQuery selector to avoid duplicating your functions

**HTML**:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <a href="#" id="b1" data-role="button"></a>
    <a href="#" id="b2" data-role="button"></a>
    <a href="#" id="b3" data-role="button"></a>
    <a href="#" id="b4" data-role="button"></a>
    <a href="#" id="next" data-role="button">Next question</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^=b]", function(event, ui)
{
   alert(this.id);
});

$(document).on("click", "#next", function(event, ui)
{
   $("#b1").prop("innerHTML", "b1 button");
   $("#b2").prop("innerHTML", "b2 button");
   $("#b3").prop("innerHTML", "b3 button");
   $("#b4").prop("innerHTML", "b4 button");

   $("#next").css("display", "none");
   $("[id^=b]").css("backgroundColor", "");
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rh6MC/2/)**

Comment: Thank you so much :-) I  looking forward in learning more about jQuery and jQuery mobile after finishing the project. I learned 2 years ago some jQuery at codeacademy.com, but I don`t used it in the practice anymore. With the interest in developing some mobile websites, I think and also hope that I`ll learn it very close soon. Thank you again Sga and have a nice day :-)

Comment: I have one little question anymore: Why should I not use onclick handlers in combination with jQuery ?